# jquery closest() tree traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting my jQuery to work correctly. I have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="hide"><!-- form --></div>
<div class="button-hide"><a href="#">Hide Form</a></div>
<div class="button-show"><a href="#">Show Form</a></div>
```

When the 'button-show' anchor is clicked, it should hide it's own div, show the above 'button-hide' div and toggle the above 'hide' div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".hide").hide();
$(".button-hide").hide();

$("div.button-show a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div.hide").slideToggle();
    $(this).closest("div.button-hide").show();
    $(this).hide();
});
});
```

None of this works for me, am I mis-using the 'closest()' command here?

Answer (score 3):

Just a bit different from the others...

```
$(".button-show a").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings(".button-hide").show();
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are matching closest on the link not the parent div. Should be .parent().closest()

Answer (score 0):

Yup, closest traverses the ancestors like parents() does. The div above it is NOT an ancestor but a sibling(look at alex's answer). if you had a container div for those divs its better to just use that as a reference like this:

```
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="hide"><!-- form --></div>
  <div class="button-hide"><a href="#">Hide Form</a></div>
  <div class="button-show"><a href="#">Show Form</a></div>
</div>
```

then in your jquery

```
$(".button-show a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".parent-container").find(".button-hide").show();
  etc
})
```